# How to create a unique id and override methods for updating an already created User object within the room database on android studio

Tags: java, android-room

**Update**
I found the issue within my program, the values are actually being saved as seen within the database inspector

The activity for adding the values never displays the current values which is what I thought they should, from this activity I can only enter new values and save

I have a user object which is already created in a separate activity via recyclerview, I want to then click into each recycler view created and update the users data within that but my update user method is not updating or storing any data at all when I enter the new data in the fields.

I know this is due to my app not being able to identify which user I'm actually trying to update but I'm unsure how to assign the id to my user object and then search for the clicked on user's id within my updateUser method in the UserDetails activity?

See below my user object created within User entity

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int uid = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Username")
    public String UserName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field1")
    public String Value1;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field2")
    public String Value2;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field3")
    public String Value3;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field4")
    public String Value4;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field5")
    public String Value5;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field6")
    public String Value6;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field7")
    public String Value7;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field8")
    public String Value8;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field9")
    public String Value9;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Field10")
    public String Value10;

    public User() { this("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""); }

    public User(String UserName, String value1, String value2, String value3, String value4, String value5, String value6, String value7, String value8, String value9, String value10 ) {
        setUserName(UserName);
        setValue1(Value1);
        setValue1(Value2);
        setValue1(Value3);
        setValue1(Value4);
        setValue1(Value5);
        setValue1(Value6);
        setValue1(Value7);
        setValue1(Value8);
        setValue1(Value9);
        setValue1(Value10);
    }




    public int getId() {

        return uid;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {

        this.uid = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {

        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {

        UserName = userName;
    }


    // Field 1 value
    public String getValue1() {

        return Value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {

        Value1 = value1;
    }

    // Field 2 value
    public String getValue2() {

        return Value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {

        Value2 = value2;
    }

    // Field 3 value
    public String getValue3() {

        return Value3;
    }

    public void setValue3(String value3) {

        Value3 = value3;
    }

    // Field 4 value
    public String getValue4() {

        return Value4;
    }

    public void setValue4(String value4) {

        Value4 = value4;
    }

    // Field 5 value
    public String getValue5() {

        return Value5;
    }

    public void setValue5(String value5) {

        Value5 = value5;
    }

    // Field 6 value
    public String getValue6() {

        return Value6;
    }

    public void setValue6(String value6) {

        Value6 = value6;
    }

    // Field 7 value
    public String getValue7() {

        return Value7;
    }

    public void setValue7(String value7) {

        Value7 = value7;
    }

    // Field 8 value
    public String getValue8() {

        return Value8;
    }

    public void setValue8(String value8) {

        Value8 = value8;
    }

    // Field 9 value
    public String getValue9() {

        return Value9;
    }

    public void setValue9(String value9) {

        Value9 = value9;
    }

    // Field 10 value
    public String getValue10() {

        return Value10;
    }

    public void setValue10(String value10) {

        Value10 = value10;
    }

}
```

See below my UserDao with my methods for inserting and updating a user

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
    List<User> getAllUsers();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE uid =:userID")
    User getUser(int userID);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertUser(User users);

    @Query("UPDATE User SET Field1 =:Value1, Field2 =:Value2, Field3 =:Value3, Field4 =:Value4, Field5 =:Value5, Field6 =:Value6, " +
            "Field7 =:Value7, Field8 =:Value8, Field6 =:Value9, Field6 =:Value9, Field10 =:Value10 WHERE uid = uid ")
    void updateUser(String Value1, String Value2, String Value3, String Value4, String Value5, String Value6, String Value7,
                    String Value8, String Value9, String Value10);

    @Update
    void updateUser(User...users);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);
}
```

See below my addnewuseractivity where a user is initially created

```
public class AddNewUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_user);

        final EditText firstNameInput =  findViewById(R.id.firstNameInput);
       /* final EditText txtField1Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField1Value);
        final EditText txtField2Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField2Value);
        final EditText txtField3Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField3Value);
        final EditText txtField4Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField4Value);
        final EditText txtField5Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField5Value);
        final EditText txtField6Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField6Value);
        final EditText txtField7Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField7Value);
        final EditText txtField8Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField8Value);
        final EditText txtField9Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField9Value);
        final EditText txtField10Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField10Value);
*/

        Button saveButton =  findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveNewUser(firstNameInput.getText().toString()); /*, txtField1Value.getText().toString(), txtField2Value.getText().toString(),
                        txtField3Value.getText().toString(), txtField4Value.getText().toString(), txtField5Value.getText().toString(),
                        txtField6Value.getText().toString(), txtField7Value.getText().toString(), txtField8Value.getText().toString(),
                        txtField9Value.getText().toString(), txtField10Value.getText().toString());*/
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveNewUser(String firstName) {
        AppDatabase db  = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

        User user = new User();
        user.UserName = firstName;
        /*user.Value1 = value1;
        user.Value2 = value2;
        user.Value3 = value3;
        user.Value4 = value4;
        user.Value5 = value5;
        user.Value6 = value6;
        user.Value7 = value7;
        user.Value8 = value8;
        user.Value9 = value9;
        user.Value10 = value10;*/

        db.userDao().insertUser(user);

        finish();

    }
}
```

See below my userdetails activity where the created user's data is supposed to be updated on press

```
public class UserDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_details);

        final EditText txtField1Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField1Value);
        final EditText txtField2Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField2Value);
        final EditText txtField3Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField3Value);
        final EditText txtField4Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField4Value);
        final EditText txtField5Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField5Value);
        final EditText txtField6Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField6Value);
        final EditText txtField7Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField7Value);
        final EditText txtField8Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField8Value);
        final EditText txtField9Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField9Value);
        final EditText txtField10Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField10Value);


        Intent detailIntent = getIntent();
        if (detailIntent != null) {
            final int userId = detailIntent.getIntExtra("userId", -1);
            if (userId != -1) {
                Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton2);
                saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        updateUser(userId, txtField1Value.getText().toString(), txtField2Value.getText().toString(),
                                txtField3Value.getText().toString(), txtField4Value.getText().toString(), txtField5Value.getText().toString(),
                                txtField6Value.getText().toString(), txtField7Value.getText().toString(), txtField8Value.getText().toString(),
                                txtField9Value.getText().toString(), txtField10Value.getText().toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

   /* public User getUser(int userID)
    {
        return AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).userDao().getUser(userID);
    }*/

    public void updateUser( int userId, String value1, String value2, String value3, String value4, String value5, String value6, String value7,
    String value8, String value9, String value10) {

        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext());


       User user = db.userDao().getUser(userId);

        user.Value1 = value1;
        user.Value2 = value2;
        user.Value3 = value3;
        user.Value4 = value4;
        user.Value5 = value5;
        user.Value6 = value6;
        user.Value7 = value7;
        user.Value8 = value8;
        user.Value9 = value9;
        user.Value10 = value10;

        db.userDao().updateUser(user);

        finish();
    }
}
```

See below my UserListAdapter and MainActivity for reference

```
public class UserListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private Context context;
    private List<User> userList;
    private ItemClickListener clickListener;

    public UserListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false);

       return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        final User user = userList.get(position);
        holder.tvFirstName.setText(this.userList.get(position).UserName);
       /* holder.tvValue1.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value1);
        holder.tvValue2.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value2);
        holder.tvValue3.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value3);
        holder.tvValue4.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value4);
        holder.tvValue5.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value5);
        holder.tvValue6.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value6);
        holder.tvValue7.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value7);
        holder.tvValue8.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value8);
        holder.tvValue9.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value9);
        holder.tvValue10.setText(this.userList.get(position).Value10);*/

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context , UserDetails.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AppDatabase.getDbInstance(context).userDao().delete(user);
                userList.remove(user);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  this.userList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvFirstName;
       /* TextView tvValue1;
        TextView tvValue2;
        TextView tvValue3;
        TextView tvValue4;
        TextView tvValue5;
        TextView tvValue6;
        TextView tvValue7;
        TextView tvValue8;
        TextView tvValue9;
        TextView tvValue10;*/

        Button deleteBtn;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
             tvFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
           /*  tvValue1 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField1Value);
             tvValue2 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField2Value);
             tvValue3 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField3Value);
             tvValue4 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField4Value);
             tvValue5 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField5Value);
             tvValue6 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField6Value);
             tvValue7 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField7Value);
             tvValue8 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField8Value);
             tvValue9 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField9Value);
             tvValue10 = view.findViewById(R.id.tvField10Value);*/

             deleteBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

        }
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView userName;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);

            itemView.setTag(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemClickListener{
    private UserListAdapter userListAdapter;

    private List<User> users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button addNewUserButton = findViewById(R.id.addNewUserButton);
        addNewUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNewUserActivity.class), 100);
            }
        });

        initRecyclerView();
        loadUserList();

    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userListAdapter);

    }

    private void loadUserList() {
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        List<User> userList =db.userDao().getAllUsers();
        userListAdapter.setUserList(userList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 100) {
            loadUserList();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        final User user = users.get(position);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When **creating** the `User`, `Room` auto-generates the primary key for you - `uid`.

When trying to **update** the `User`, it is you, who need to provide the `uid`.

```
public void updateUser(int usertID, String value1...value10) {

    AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    User user =  new User();
    user.uid = userUID // <------------
    user.Value1 = value1;
    ...
    user.Value10 = value10;

    db.userDao().updateUser(user);

    finish();
}
```

I think you are missing passing the user ID to the detail activity as well.

UserListAdapter

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , UserDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("userId", user.uid)
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

UserDetails activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_details);

    final EditText txtField1Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField1Value);
    ...
    final EditText txtField10Value = findViewById(R.id.txtField10Value);

    Intent detailIntent = getIntent();
    if (detailIntent != null) {
        int userId = detailIntent.getIntExtra("userId", -1);
        if (userId != -1) {
            Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton2);
            saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    updateUser(
                        userId
                        txtField1Value.getText().toString(), 
                        ...
                        txtField10Value.getText().toString());
            }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, when adding the userID to my updateUser method this is fine however above within my onClick where the field values are assigned this generates an error as I assume it is expecting the userID to be assigned in that onClick just as the values 1 - 10 are?

Comment: Well, yes. I think you might have not posted full code but you have `getUser(int userID)` there so I assumed you have a way how to get the `userID`?

Comment: See above the updated updateUser with your suggested change, I thought my getUser method would return the userID automatically from the database as its autogenerated.  I called this within my updateUser at the bottom but does this need assigned in the onclick instead to avoid getting the error ?

Comment: Where do you get the `userID` of the user you are trying to modify?

Comment: I thought the getUser method would return it from the database using the getUser query in the UserDao

Comment: @xAaron Yes, `getUser(int userID)` would return the User but it needs `userID` to do so. Do you get the `userID` somewhere? (I updated the answer based on what I think is wrong)

Comment: Okay I made your changes and there are no errors but the values are still not updated upon pressing the save button in the UserDetails activity, is this because I have not referenced them in the adapter?

Comment: You mean in the `MainActivity`? Well you are not updating them there. If you kill the app and open it again, it should be updated?